# Needleman Wunsch with affine gap penalty

Tags: dynamic, needleman-wunsch

Can someone provide an example where an affine gap penalty would eventually give a different result than running NW on two sequences with a fixed gap penalty ?

Answer (score 0):

[Affine Gap Penalty Model:](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/psa/emboss_needle/nucleotide.html)

```
AAAGAATTCA
|||    |||
AAA----TCA
```

Notice: To get an optimal global alignment, you need to change "End Gap Penalty" to true in "STEP 2 - Set your pairwise alignment options"

[Fixed Gap Penalty Model:](http://experiments.mostafa.io/public/needleman-wunsch/)

```
AAAGAATTCA
|||   | ||
AAA---T-CA
```